# how to enable intellisence in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

when I type something wrong in my .py script it doesn't give me a red wavy line under the word like this:

```
prnt("hello "
```

it should give me an error but it doesn't, how should I fix?

Comment: Dumb question, but have you added the python extension?

Comment: @MisterPositive thank you so much, problem solved :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Click on the square icon on the left hand side of VSCode. Then search for extensions and pick a Python extension to use.

[image]